# LoggerAwareInterface Not Found in mPdf

Tags: php, mpdf

I am using core PHP and my requirement is to create a PDF from database data using simple PHP. I dont have much knowledge on composer and packegist and all. I just want to convert a HTML table to PDF. For that I am using php **mPDF** library.

I am referring to **[this tutorial](https://www.phpflow.com/php/create-pdf-file-using-mpdf-php/)**.

It says:

```
// include the library class mPDF at the end of the index.php file.
include('src/Mpdf.php');
$mpdf = new mPDF();
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);

// call watermark content aand image
$mpdf->SetWatermarkText('phpflow.COM');
$mpdf->showWatermarkText = true;
$mpdf->watermarkTextAlpha = 0.1;

// save the file put which location you need folder/filname
$mpdf->Output("phpflow.pdf", 'F');

//out put in browser below output function
$mpdf->Output();
```

But after including it throws an error

> Interface 'Psr\Log\LoggerAwareInterface' not found on line 56

So how can I resolve this. In the GitHub documentation it is suggested to add

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
$mpdf->WriteHTML('<h1>Hello world!</h1>');
$mpdf->Output();
```

But when I download the plugin it does not have any folder with name vendor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Use composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#require) as the tutorial suggests to fetch mpdf as a dependency and build autoloading:

```
composer require mpdf/mpdf
```

or use mPDF 6.x version which does not require these dependencies.

Note that

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
```

is the constructor for 7.x version, use

```
$mpdf = new mPDF();
```

for 6.x only.

Comment: thanks.! can you provide link to download Ver 6.X Download Link